How to auth wallet with ton connect? (Python)
I have link, which opens a ton wallet on Android. I want to create new ton wallet with Python and authorize in app. I know that it is just post request, but how to do it right?
Example of link:
tc://?v=2&id=538d2f45a78e55edd4f2c415648142270e840eaa7228426630172d840fa7083b&r=%7B%22manifestUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmanifest.json%22%2C%22items%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22ton_addr%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22ton_proof%22%2C%22payload%22%3A%22SCYXKCw2vMEsFW7cDv6CxoVIdj%2BGkUWtDV%2BBjXHa1h4%3D%22%7D%5D%7D
I watched source code of wallets, I searching information in Google.
ChatGPT gave me this code, but it does not work:
import requests
import json
import base64
from urllib.parse import unquote

def parse_tc_url(tc_url):
    # Извлекаем часть r из ссылки
    url_parts = tc_url.split('?')
    if len(url_parts) < 2:
        raise ValueError("Неверная tc-ссылка")
    
    params = url_parts[1]
    r_param = params.split('&')[-1]

    # Декодируем r параметр
    raw_r = unquote(r_param.split('=')[1])
    return json.loads(raw_r)

def authorize_with_ton_connect(tc_url):
    # Парсинг ссылки
    data = parse_tc_url(tc_url)

    # Получение полей для авторизации
    ton_addr = next(item['name'] for item in data['items'] if item['name'] == "ton_addr")
    ton_proof = next(item['payload'] for item in data['items'] if item['name'] == "ton_proof")

    # URL для отправки данных авторизации
    auth_url = "https://example.com/auth"  # Замените на ваш действительный URL для авторизации

    # Подготовка данных для POST-запроса
    auth_data = {
        "ton_addr": ton_addr,
        "ton_proof": ton_proof
    }

    # Выполнение POST-запроса
    response = requests.post(auth_url, json=auth_data)

    # Проверка результата
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Ошибка при авторизации: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")

# Пример ссылки
tc_url = "tc://?v=2&id=757c46d50210689da97a3241822065fa8ce01718fc7d5981903a46bffbbbe011&r=%7B%22manifestUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmanifest.json%22%2C%22items%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22ton_addr%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22ton_proof%22%2C%22payload%22%3A%22EH44OZ1oaKCnjQewmDcyGTtb4GpgKI12bZJYzhVtkgU%3D%22%7D%5D%7D"

try:
    auth_response = authorize_with_ton_connect(tc_url)
    print("Успешная авторизация! Информация:", auth_response)
except Exception as e:
    print("Ошибка:", e)

